# Angular scope.$watch() equivalent in Rivets.js

Tags: javascript, rivets.js

In angularjs `scope.$watch()` can be used to execute a function each time a variable value changes.

```
scope.$watch('myvar', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  changeCallback();
});
```

(The angularjs sample is only for showing what i want to do. I want to use only rivets.js, not anglarjs at all.)

I could use an event listener on the element that can change the value, but then i have to have event listeners everywhere where the variable value might get changed from.

```
<input type='text' rv-on-change='changeCallback' rv-value='myvar'>
```

Or if the value gets changed from javascript code i would have to execute the change function from there too.

```
myvar = 'changed value';
changeCallbacl()
```

QUESTION: Is there a way to execute a function each time a variable value changes in rivers.js without adding any code to the other end where the value gets changed from?

Comment: Create a custom directive and bind scope.$watch there which will find changes in rv-value

Comment: I tried to make the question more clear by adding that i want to use only rivets.js without angularjs. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution here http://jsfiddle.net/nsisodiya/2mkjx44j/ . You need to use sightglass wich is a dependency for rivets and included in rivets.bundled.min.js .

```
// configure sightlass with same adapters as rivets
sightglass.adapters = rivets.adapters;
sightglass.root = '.';

// listen for changes on list.val 
// list is an object and val is property to listen for changes on
sightglass(list, 'val', function() {
  log('value changed...');
});
```

Here is a working sample on codepen
http://codepen.io/mstadius/pen/azroda

And here is code of same sample

html

```
<div id='app'>{list.val}<br>
<input rv-value='list.val'><br>
  <button rv-on-click='list.reset'>Reset</button>
</div>
<div id='log'></div>
```

js

```
  var log = function(msg){
    $('#log').prepend('<div>'+msg+'</div>');
  };

  var list = {
    val: 1
    , reset: function(){
      log('Clicked reset...');
      list.val = 1;
    }
  };
  var a = rivets.bind($('#app'), {list: list});

  sightglass.adapters = rivets.adapters;
  sightglass.root = '.';

  sightglass(list, 'val', function() {
    log('value changed...');
  });
```